# Phonetic Symbols Patent Category

Tags: phonetic

Can a new invention of phonetic symbols (just like IPA) be categorized as process or article of manufacture?

Comment: As an aside, why are you interested in the statutory category? It's probably the least important of all the requirements for a patent (in the sense that it's more of a formality that can be fixed by claim amendments than anything else). There's nothing wrong with your question if that is all you're interested in, but it just strikes me that you may be trying to get at an underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two criteria for subject matter eligibility:

1. Does the claimed invention fall into one of the statutory categories of invention (process, machine, manufacture, composition)?
2. Does the claimed invention relate to patent-eligible subject matter?

You have specifically asked about the first criterion. Since this turns on what the *claimed* invention is, the answer depends on how your claims are constructed. For example, claim for a method of using phonetic symbols is clearly a process, whereas a claim for a piece of paper displaying phonetic symbols would be an article of manufacture.

Since it is easy to adjust your claims to fall into a suitable category, the first criterion is a low hurdle to cross.

You haven't asked about the second criterion, but I'll mention it anyway. Even if a claimed invention falls into a statutory category, it may still be patent-ineligible. For example, an abstract method is patent-ineligible.

In your case, phonetic symbols really have no meaning other than when read by a user. They are therefore analogous to printed matter (such as the words in a book). Printed matter per se is patent-ineligible (unless it effectively causes an effect in a computer, like computer instructions). As such, even if you had a suitable relating to your phonetic symbol system, it would not be patentable.

There is no simple way to overcome this, as the problem relates to the core of the invention. It therefore requires further inventing.

For example, if you configured the symbols such that they could be read by a computer and converted to synthesized speech, that would probably be patent-eligible subject matter. But then you're really talking about an entirely different invention.

Comment: I find this answer a bit confusing. "It depends on how it is claimed", but if it isn't patent eligible, you would be able to claim. I think you are being clever, but it might be taken as ambiguous.

Comment: @EricShain It's two different criteria. The first (which depends on the claim) is whether it falls into a statutory category. A claim for "a method of using phonetic symbols" absolutely does, since it's a process. The second is whether it's patent-eligible. In this case, no, because it's just abstract. So a claim can quite legitimately fall into a statutory category, but relate to patent-ineligible subject matter.

Comment: I understand, but I think the answer would be clearer if you stated the fact it isn’t patent eligible first and foremost. It may be obvious to you, but clearly not to the question poster.

Comment: What would be the possible ways to elevate it out of abstract idea?

Comment: @EricShain A fair criticism actually. I've reworked my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Patent2018 I've tried to address this in the new answer. But in short, it requires a bit more inventing, or some discovery of a surprising effect of your system, or something of that nature.

Comment: https://patents.google.com/patent/US7004758B2/en?oq=7004758 This was granted.  But it is not clear if it is a process.

Comment: @Patent2018 I would venture to say you wouldn't get something like that through these days (unless you had a very permissive examiner).

Answer (score 1):

Not now. A symbol would be considered an abstract concept and wouldn't be patented, as such. The new symbols printed on a piece of paper would be an article of manufacture, but under the "printed matter doctrine" if the only difference from the prior art is the content of some printing, it is not patently different from the prior art. A new way to print a symbol on sheet metal is a process. The printing process would not likely be specific to printing the newly created symbol system.